# SQL COLUMN Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Select * from a 
inner join b 
on a.1=b.2

update table a 
set a.2=b.3 
from a 
inner join b 
on a.1=b.2
```

I am trying to update a column in a table in SQL.

Initially I am selecting the data from the column using a join which rows needs to be updated (count would be 40000). Then I run the update statement to update the column with new values (updated count 2000). The count from join is always more than the update count.

When i go back and perform the join I get count as zero.

I couldn't understand why I am getting the difference. Can anyone please assist?

Thanks

Comment: Because there are multiple rows in tableB that match some rows in tableA.

Comment: And, as a bonus, what with `FROM` being a non-standard extension to SQL, it's not even guaranteed *which* rows from `B` were used to supply the final values that were used in `A`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, the problem is that multiple values in `b` match one or more values in `a`.

If you want equal counts, try running the queries like this:

```
Select count(*)
from a 
where exists (select 1 from b where a.1 = b.2);
```

And then:

```
update table a 
    set a.2 = b.3 
    where exists (select 1 from b where a.1 = b.2);
```

If the tables have not changed between the queries, then they should report the same number of rows.